# two-step devise signup -- email (pg 1) then password (pg 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, registration

How can I break up the devise signup form into two steps on two different pages?

Page 1: User enters email, clicks submit.
Page 2: User enters password, clicks submit.

This is a common signup flow and I couldn't find any examples, how-tos or questions about it. It seems worth asking for the benefit of all of us beginner Rails monkeys. Of course I'd like to save the email even if the user neglects to enter a password on the second page.

Really appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use a multi-stage form with sessions. There is a great Railscast here on the topic http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms Sessions are a way of preserving data about a user from one page to the next without the explicit need for you to set his cookies, recognize them etc. Rails sessions take care of all of the recognition.

Comment: I think the problem with this is that if the user doesn't submit a password then I can't save the email.